# Making a complete graph with one edge in diffrent color

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Hi guys I have a problem creating a graph in latex and I will appreciate some help. I want this picture but with the edge between 1 and 4 in thick red. Also If I can somehow have the  vertices named and display their names that will be very helpful. I really appreciate input thank you!!!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\x-1)*360/4}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.15cm] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {};
  } 
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {1,...,3}{%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{%
     \path (N-\x) edge[ultra thin,-] (N-\y);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the red part :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\x-1)*360/4}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.15cm] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {\x};
  } 
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {1,...,3}{%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{%
      \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumcomp{\x}{=}{1}} and test {\ifnumcomp{\y}{=}{4}} }
      {\path (N-\x) edge[ultra thin, draw=red,-] (N-\y);}
      {\path (N-\x) edge[ultra thin,-] (N-\y);}
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See if the following (simple) solution works for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.15cm] (N\x) at ({(\x-1)*90}:1.4cm) {};
  }
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3}{%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{%
        \ifnum\x=3 
    \path (N\x) edge[draw=red,ultra thin] (N\y);
        \else
    \path (N\x) edge[ultra thin] (N\y);
        \fi
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The highlighted edge is between 3 and 4, not 1 and 4 here?

Comment: @jak123, you have right. I rotate picture for 90 degrees. It is corrected now. However, this doesn't change the showed way how to highlight desired path.